# Fill/interpolate no data values on raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst

I have a large stack of rasters for snow cover every day for the past fifteen years. Each pixel can have one of three values: snow, no snow, or No Data due to cloud cover.

I want to fill those no data values with data from the following days, i.e. If 12/1/2002 has a blank spot due to clouds, fill that spot with the data from the 12/2/2002 raster. I do not want to alter the other pixels at all- just the blank/No Data pixels.

I'm using ArcMap 10.1

Is this an approach which will fill the No Data values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a con function.  The con function will look at every pixel in the in_conditional_raster (the current raster being evaluated.  If the pixel equals NoData is true, then replace that pixel with the value from the following day, if it is false (the pixel has data) do nothing.  [Here is a link to the Con tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm).  If your file names are something like 20021202 (YYYYMMDD) then it will be easy iterate though them.  Of course it will get more complicated if the following day also has a NoData value.